# DataStax Java Driver 4.0: is object mapping going to be supported?

Tags: java, cassandra, annotations, mapping, datastax-java-driver

On March 2019 DataStax Java Driver v4.0.0 was released, and my project should plan future migration to it, however I was not able to found any mentioning of object mapping as [it was done](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/object_mapper/) in 3.x.x version.

I checked DataStax GitHub and JIRA and there is nothing that can help.

Is it going to be supported? If yes, can you share a link to the repository location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be supported in driver 4.1. Please see [this mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/d/msg/java-driver-user/oOPViqIiSa4/ENzkk3kRCQAJ), and the ticket in the open source Jira:
https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-2078